# How to define expected body of response containing list of indefinite number of JSON items in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I just started learning how to test API in python so please bear with me.

I want to test the endpoint that returns all users from database. My expected body looks like below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "63811d56f6bea6b0dcb35342",
    "email": "jan_kowalski@poczta.com",
    "email_confirmed": "False",
    "is_active": true,
    "password": "12345",
    "secret": "hdoofdgxksesdjvfrzsfedgqzouqnxyk",
    "first_name": "Jan",
    "last_name": "Kowalski",
    "city": "Krakow",
    "postal_code": "97-406",
    "address": "ul. NMP 6"
  },
  {
    "_id": "63811d6ef6bea6b0dcb35343",
    "email": "adam_kowalski@poczta.com",
    "email_confirmed": "False",
    "is_active": true,
    "password": "12345",
    "secret": "vxnktmnsuflvloduewglwdtrgplccqoe",
    "first_name": "Jan",
    "last_name": "Kowalski",
    "city": "Krakow",
    "postal_code": "97-406",
    "address": "ul. NMP 6"
  }
]
```

Here is my test:

```
from app import main

def test_get_all_users(test_app):
    response = test_app.get("/user/all")
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I should also add some checking if the resposne JSON is correct:

```
assert response.json() == {*my json*}
```

How to set assert response.json() to handle unknown number of JSON items?

Comment: What do you mean by JSON items? The number of users or JSON properties?

Comment: I can have one or more users in the database. One JSON item is one user.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the number of users that will be returned each time the test is run, the best you can do is check if each user in the response contains all the properties that are expected. Something like below:

```py
from app import main

def test_get_all_users(test_app):
    response = test_app.get("/user/all")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    users = response.json()
    for user in users:
        assert user["_id"]
        assert user["email"]
        assert user["email_confirmed"]
        assert user["is_active"]
        assert user["password"]
        assert user["secret"]
        assert user["first_name"]
        assert user["last_name"]
        assert user["city"]
        assert user["postal_code"]
        assert user["address"]
```

You could also check the types of the properties with `assert type(user["_id"]) == str` and so on.

However, the best test would be to have a known set of data which you can check when it is returned. To do that, if possible on your conditions, you could write a fixture that would create the database and then the users with certain properties so you could check their data later in a deterministic way and later destroy the database to have a fresh environment when the tests are run again.